# Не могу найти и установить пакет расширения для звука PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyqt5, аудио

Необходимо воспроизвести короткие звуки для аварийных сообщений не занимая основной поток.

Не могу найти и подобрать пакет расширений для этой цели. Знаю что есть класс `QSound`. У меня `ОС Windows 10 Pro 64bit 20H2`

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def main():
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "output.wav")

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    QtMultimedia.QSound.play(filename)


    # end in 5 seconds:
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5 * 1000, app.quit)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Все работает, но нет звука. Сам файл воспроизводится.
Потом решил воспроизвести через pyaudio. Это глупо так как есть средства в фреймворке QT.

```
    import pyaudio               # воспроизведение звука
    import wave                  # для потока звука
    import sys
    
    
    # p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    # for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    # print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])
    CHUNK = 1024
    wf = wave.open('output.wav', 'rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
    while data != '':
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/JIoBuboJIT/PycharmProjects/SAU_TKA_Hispano_Suiza/d.py", line 10, in <module>
    wf = wave.open('output.wav', 'rb')
  File "C:\Python382\lib\wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Python382\lib\wave.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Python382\lib\wave.py", line 131, in initfp
    raise Error('file does not start with RIFF id')
wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Ошибка и звука не было. Потом решил воспроизвести по другому через pyglet. Звук был.

```
import pyglet

song = pyglet.media.load('output.wav')
song.play()
# song.seek(0)
pyglet.app.run()
# sdfsadf

from threading import Thread

song = pyglet.media.load("output.wav")
Thread(target=song.play).start()
pyglet.app.run()
pyglet.app.exit()
```

Не могу найти нормальную информацию для чайников по данному вопросу. Почему нет звука если воспроизвести через QtMultimedia.QSound.play(filename) ? Помогите кто чем может.

Решил попробовать через QSoundEffect с указанием конкретной директории. Столкнулся с проблемой указания аргумента для команды Url= . В документации на С++ не ясно выражено что и как https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html.

```
QSoundEffect effect;
effect.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("engine.wav"));
effect.setLoopCount(QSoundEffect::Infinite);
effect.setVolume(0.25f);
effect.play();
```

---

**Update**

Вот мой код и конечно ошибка fromLocalFile. Пытался заменить на путь, переменную с указанием пути и ошибка. Не могу понять что необходимо для данного аргумента и как записать?

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
    import sys
    
    def main():
        app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
        sss = QtMultimedia.QSoundEffect
        sss.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("output.wav"))
        sss.play()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5 * 1000, app.quit)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

> TypeError: setSource(self, QUrl): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QSoundEffect'

Comment: Попробуйте задать `QtMultimedia.QSound.play("output.wav")` - у меня работает

Comment: К сожалению звука нет. Уже пробовал. Файл программы находится в одной папке вместе со звуковым файлом. Как правильно указать точный или абсолютный путь к файлу?

Comment: Пробовал указывать не верное имя файла и путь QtMultimedia.QSound.play("C:\Python382\output.wav") ошибок нет, хотя фалов таких нет. Получается ошибки не фиксирует и в этом может быть причина. Pyglet воспроизвел файл. Могла установка данного расширения повлиять на работу QtMultimedia.QSound ? Мне нужны слоты и возможность работа со средствами данного фреймворка, а не делать костыли. Помогите чайнику)

Comment: Я указал просто имя файла

Comment: Alexander Chernin Уже пробовал по разному и звука нет. QtMultimedia.QSound.play("output.wav") Так тоже как вы и писали. Почему может не быть звука? Как можно проверить работу QtMultimedia? Если у вас все работает значит что то у меня с расширениями установленными?

Comment: Странно, у меня `Windows` и ваш пример (`QtMultimedia.QSound.play(filename)`)  работает и звук есть.
Настораживает то, что если указывать не верное имя файла - 
у меня выдает ошибку `QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source`. 
1. Какая ОС у вас? 2. Как вы запускаете ваш скрипт? 
3. Запустите вашу программу из консоли/терминала/CMD `python main.py`, что вы получаете?

Comment: C:\Users\JIoBuboJIT>python C:\Python382\d.py
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:output.wav  Вот что выдало.

Comment: так уже лучше. Это вам выдало когда вы указали не правильное имя `output12345.wav`, так ? или правильное `output.wav` ? Какая у вас ОС ? Покажите результат `print(f'filename -> {filename}')`

Comment: C:\Python382\python.exe C:/Users/JIoBuboJIT/PycharmProjects/SAU_TKA_Hispano_Suiza/d.py
filename -> C:\Users\JIoBuboJIT\PycharmProjects\SAU_TKA_Hispano_Suiza\output.wav

Process finished with exit code 0   Это результат запроса в коде. Название файла менял, но почему то ошибка такая же про кодировку и видимо это первое до чего он доходит Error decoding source file.

Comment: `Какая ОС у вас?` 
Попробуйте перейти в каталог где лежат `d.py` и `output.wav` и запустите оттуда  из консоли/терминала/CMD `python d.py`

Comment: filename -> C:\Users\JIoBuboJIT\PycharmProjects\SAU_TKA_Hispano_Suiza\output.wav
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:///C:/Users/JIoBuboJIT/PycharmProjects/SAU_TKA_Hispano_Suiza/output.wav  сначала зашел в директорию и потом запустил.  ОС Windows 10 Pro 64bit 20H2

Comment: Попробуйте переложить `d.py` и `output.wav` в корень диска `C:`, перейдите в на `C:\ ` и запустите `python d.py`. Все делаем в `CMD`!

Comment: C:\Users\JIoBuboJIT>python C:\d.py
filename -> C:\output.wav
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:///C:/output.wav

C:\Users\JIoBuboJIT>python C:/d.py
filename -> C:\output.wav
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:///C:/output.wav                                       Все делаю в CMD. Сделал двумя способами с разными \ и ошибка та же.

Comment: https://together.jolla.com/question/53394/qsoundeffectpulseaudio-error-decoding-sourc/  вот тут говорится о моей проблеме возможно, но я не понимаю что значит (If you haven't already created one go to File | New | Qt | Qt Resource File   Click Add existing files then select sound files you want)  где, в каком приложении и как мне нужно прикрепить данные файлы. Видимо указание пути к файлу не прописывается почему то.

Comment: я же вам писал запустите `python d.py` ничего не добавляйте перед `d.py`, а также попробуйте с другим `name.wav`

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>python d.py
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:output.wav

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python d.py
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:oudtput.wav  Пробовал изменять имя несуществующего файла, место файла, перенес в директорию system32) . Результат один и тот же.

Comment: Sorry, последний раз, переложите `d.py` и `output.wav` в корень диска `C:`. 
В CMD запустие `C:\>python d.py`, а не `C:\WINDOWS\system32>python d.py`
Попробуйте с другим `name.wav` - это значит не переименовывать `output.wav` в `name.wav`, 
а нужно взять ДРУГОЙ `.wav`.

Comment: C:\>python help.py
filename -> C:\help.wav
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:///C:/help.wav    скачал wav файл, взял другой файл, открыл блокнот, написал код тот же самый только имя файла другое и все тоже самое.      Взял другой формат  C:\>python help.py
filename -> C:\Misogi - Eyesclosed (Ft. Bones).mp3
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:///C:/Misogi - Eyesclosed (Ft. Bones).mp3  ошибка такая же

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос еще одним подходом через QSoundEffect. Там не получается из-за аргумента который нужно указать для определения пути.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QSoundEffect` обеспечивает способ воспроизведения звуковых эффектов с малой задержкой.

Добавьте скобки:

```
#                              vv
sss = QtMultimedia.QSoundEffect()
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

def main():
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    
    sss = QtMultimedia.QSoundEffect()                        # + ()
    
    sss.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("cl.wav"))
    sss.play()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5 * 1000, app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ошибок больше таких нет. Все та же со звуком. C:\Users\JIoBuboJIT\PycharmProjects\SAU_TKA_Hispano_Suiza>python help.py
QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source file:output.wav

Comment: @JIoBuboJIT у меня все предложенное вами работает.